# Using Connect\Express middleware within custom middleware

Tags: node.js, express, connect

Is it viable to use popular Connect middleware within your custom middleware?

For example, I'm writing some authentication middleware, which obviously relies quite heavily on Connect's `cookieParser()` and `session` methods. These methods are middleware, so they require `request`, `response` and `next` parameters to be passed. The obvious option is to simply make sure I'm adding them to the middleware stack before I add my authentication middleware like so:

app.js:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'))
   .use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}))
   .use(my_auth_middleware())
```

But this seems a bit cumbersome as my middleware relies on the first two methods in order to do stuff with the `req.session`.

The other obvious way to do it would be to pass the app into my middleware, and then call the `cookieParser()` and `session` methods within, but because they are both middleware I would have to add them to the stack, which feels wrong:

my_auth_middleware.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}));

    return function(req, res, next){

        // do stuff with req.session

        next();

    }
}
```

Can anyone confirm that this is a logical way to do things? Is there an argument for keeping the `cookieParser()` and `session` methods out of my middleware?

Obviously I'm using Express in these examples, but I'm aware these methods originate from Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your first setup. It's rather explicit (you could perhaps add a comment stating that `my_auth_middleware()` relies on the other two), and therefore pretty obvious to anyone looking at your code.

Your second example almost hides the fact that the other two middleware are being used. They also move some of your applications' configuration (secrets and cookie name) to a separate file, which might be confusing. And personally I don't like passing `app` around.

FWIW, `express.session` also needs `express.cookieParser` to work, but it leaves it up to the programmer to load it.

Comment: Wanted to wait a bit before accepting to see if this sparked debate. Doesn't look like anybody has anything further to add so I'll accept. Cheers.